# How to positioned widget toLeftOf or toRightOf in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I first want to center one widget and then add another widget to the right of the center widget.
Currently, flutter APIs are not feasible for this. In android, it can be easily done in relative layout or constraint layout.

[image]

I tried with some hack with MediaQuery,

```
Stack(
  children: [
      Center(child: Text(17)),
      Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      left: (screenWidth / 2) + (screenWidth / 3),
      child: Column(
          children: []
      )
```

)

How to try this in an easy way or a proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found used https://pub.dev/packages/align_positioned

```
AlignPositioned.relative(
                    Text(day.englishDate.toString(),
                        textScaleFactor: 3, style: dayTextStyle),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        ....
                      ],
                    ),
                    moveByChildWidth: 1.1,
                    minChildWidthRatio: 1,
                    moveByChildHeight: 0.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Align` widget for this.

Code Example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SandBox extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight, //aligns the child widget to the right center
            child: Text('17'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you 

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it can help you to achieve what you want:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 30,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Text('17'),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Container(
                width: 10,
                height: 10,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or you can adjust it using some calculations using `MediaQuery` and `Stack`.
You can use [badges](https://pub.dev/packages/badges) package to achieve this goal.

Answer (score -1):

Please use `Align` along with `Row`.

here is simple code to achieve this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
        
          children:[
                    Align(
                      child : Row( 
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
                        children:[ 
                          Padding(child: Text('Left'),padding: EdgeInsets.all(5)),
                          Text('Center widget'), 
                           Padding(child: Text('Right'),padding: EdgeInsets.all(5))
                        ]) , 
                      alignment: Alignment.center),
                 
                   ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the output: [image]